# Desperately need to add directions to android project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, google-directions-api

I have been pondering and web surfing on this for **days**, but after around **0** productivity for a week I have decided to ask this vague question. My question- Could anyone pleeease tell me how to implement directions into my android project?

To elaborate, the exact function for which I am asking here is highlighted in the next paragraph.

The goal for my project: Whenever a user types in a location(it will hide the keyboard after clicking go), it will go to that location and place a marker there. **Then it will display the route with the shortest travel time between the current location and the marker.** I don't know how to limit the country the user can search locations within, but I am pretty sure that will be easy. I already have bits and pieces of my end goal, but not really what I need.

Finally this is my MainActivity. I have referenced a few classes I haven't added here so, simply ask if you need them to run this code in your own compiler or otherwise:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9002;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String LOGTAG = "Maps";

    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationListener mListener;
    private Marker marker;

    ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (initMap()) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hmmm. Maps didn't load.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There's something wrong with your play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        UiSettings config = mMap.getUiSettings();
        config.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        config.setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.legal:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LicenseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MapStateManager mgr = new MapStateManager(this);
        CameraPosition position = mgr.getSavedCameraPosition();
        if (position != null) {
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
            mMap.moveCamera(update);
            mMap.setMapType(mgr.getSavedMapType());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        MapStateManager mgr = new MapStateManager(this);
        mgr.saveMapState(mMap);
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            MapFragment mapFrag =
                    (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
                              float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String location = et.getText().toString();
        if (location.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);

        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void showCurrentLocation(MenuItem item) {
        int permCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            Location currentlocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (currentlocation == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't find you!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(
                        currentlocation.getLatitude(),
                        currentlocation.getLongitude()
                );
                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        latlng, 15
                );
                mMap.animateCamera(update);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        int permCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Go go go!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    gotoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 15);
                }
            };

            LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
            request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            request.setInterval(20000);
            request.setFastestInterval(0);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, request, mListener
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: this was juuuuust asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400355/google-directions-api-implementation-on-android/38400815

Comment: @mastrgamr wow! It didn't pop up as related when I was typing the question in, and I coudn't find this earlier(obviously because it happened an hour ago). Thank a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this library on github:

[jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android)

I use it on my projects, and you can clone it and modify it to your specific needs.

The logic you have in the question seems sound on first glance, but to limit search locations I would probably just take whatever query is in the search box and compare it to see if it's within a specified `LatLngBounds` you provide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Couldn't reply sooner because I didn't expect a reply this quick(Went AFK in the never ending search for good coffee)! As for your answer, I don't really understand what the github project is about. Do I have to add it through maven or gradle so I get ease of use? Please explain to my primordial mind!

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy If you scroll down a bit on the page linked you can find instructions on how to use it. You add it via gradle, add the RoutingListener to your class that referenced the `GoogleMap`, and handle it like shown on this page: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/directions/sample/MainActivity.java#L382

Comment: I had already scrolled down the page and understood some stuff(sorry I didn't mention this earlier). How do I specify where the route has to go through?

Comment: @Rainbowteddycoderguy the waypoints take 2 `LatLng` points https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/directions/sample/MainActivity.java#L358

Comment: One qq.. do I instantiate the Routing object in the onCreate method?

Comment: You can. If later you'd want to add it to some button click, you can do it there too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117445/discussion-between-mastrgamr-and-rainbow-teddy-coder-guy).

Comment: Hello again! I have a qq for you. How do I integrate the "Legs" function using your repo? Thanks!